# SWT Text widget behave as Command promt

Tags: java, swt

I am  trying to create a applicatin with SWT Text widget. The Text widget should act as command prompt asking input but not allowed to be delete after pressed enter. but characters can be deleted on same line before enter. Is this possible? Thanks, Tor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to set up a two widget layout. Create one component for holding the terminal screen (non-editable) and a `Text` widget that holds your input and is editable. 
Following API should give you an idea on how to implement this behavior:

- Every [`Text`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FText.html) widget has a `setEditable(boolean)` method to set wether it can be edited or not.
- You can pass constants from class `SWT` to the constructor. Ex.:

  ```
  new Text(shell, SWT.SINGLE) // creates single line text field
  new Text(shell, SWT.MULTI)  // crates a multi line text field
  ```
- Maybe adding a [`KeyListener`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FText.html) will help you.